# Create a collection of different types inherited from abstract parent class

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, collections

There most likely is a better way to solve this problem than my suggestion in the title. Here is the problem:

```
abstract class BaseClass 
{
      abstract public void DoSomething();
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass 
{
      public override DoSomething();
}

class OtherClass
{
    //Here is what I want to do for two elements
      ChildClass foo = new ChildClass();
      SomeOtherChildClass bar = new SomeOtherChildClass();
      foo.DoSomething();
      bar.DoSomething();
}
```

i want to do this for a lot more elements. I don't want to make their own variables and I don't want to create separate lists for each child class. I don't actually want to have to know what child classes there are as long as they inherit BaseClass  and have DoSomething(). So I can do something like: myColelction.ForEach(i => i.DoSomething()); to

I think I need some quite permissive collection. I thought of IEnumable and Concatting on the new elements, but of course you can't do that when BaseClass is abstract.

The alternative (i can think of) is using events. But there may be multiple instances of OtherClass and i don't want to trigger things I shouldn't. Maybe I'm wrong, but i don't know much about events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just need a List of the base class type, e.g.

```
List<BaseClass> myCollection
```

e.g. you can do

```
myCollection.Add(new ChildClass());
myCollection.Add(new SecondChildClass());
```

and you can

```
myCollection.Foreach(i => i.DoSomething());
```